# Find the number of liters of saline solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How many liters of 25% of saline solution must be added to 3 liters of 10% of saline solution to obtain 15% saline solution ?
My turn :
Let the total number of liters of the saline solution =$x$
And the required number of liters is $y$ , then
$$xy + 3 = 0.15 y $$
But there is no another information to form a second equation of $x , y $ ?

Comment: I don't understand the product term, $xy$.  Nor do I understand what $x$ is...there appears to be only one variable in the problem, namely the number of liters of saline you need to add.  What do you mean by $x$?

Comment: Where, for example, do you use the fact that the saline you are adding is $25\%$?  Where do you use the fact that the original saline is $10\%$?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using $2$ variables, I think using $1$ variable is more convenient and easier to understand.

$3\cdot0.1 + x\cdot 0.25 = (3+x)\cdot 0.15$

Where x is the amount of liters of 25% saline solution.

The total number of liters of the after creating a 15% solution would be $3       +$X

Comment: Does the number of liters of 25% differ from the number of liters of 100% ? @Johny park

Comment: Hi, the statement you have posted did not mention anything about 100% concentration of saline solution. The question only mentions 15%, 10%, and 25% concentration of concentration, respectively. @HussienMohamed

Comment: The first idea got into my brain is the sum must be 15% of the total amount of the solution . Why is idea wrong ?@Johnny Park

Comment: Hi, I think you are thinking the answer should be 15% of the total amount, while the question is asking 15% “concentration”. Thinking of it as salt water. So there is salt water with 10% concentration (10g per 100ml) and 25% concentration (25g per 100ml). If you have 3L of 10% concentration, how many X liters of the 25% concentration do you have add so that the 3L of 10% concentration becomes (3+X)L of 15% concentration (15g per 100ml)? @HussienMohamed

Comment: Thank you very much for your illustration @Johnny Park